FULL OUTER JOIN on TWO MYSQL TABLES WITH 3 RELATING COLUMNS
I have two tables I want to compare data from. The query of the first table is below and it gives me 12 rows.
***** 1st Query ************
SELECT distinct a.pnr AS PNR, a.station_code as Station,a.date as Date,
sum(a.allamount) as TsrAmount
from daily_posting a 
Where a.date between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' and a.station_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
group by a.date,a.station_code,a.pnr 

The second query which is similar gives me 17 rows
******* 2nd Query *********
SELECT distinct b.pnr_NO AS PNR, b.sR_code as Station,b.date_OF_ACTION as Date,
ABS(
sum(b.LOC_TAX_AMOUNT + b.LOC_PAX_FARE + b.LOC_SURCHARGE_AMOUNT + b.LOC_SERVICE_FEE_AMOUNT )) 
as CRAmount 
from ticketsalesdetails b
Where b.date_of_action between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' and b.sr_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
group by b.date_of_action,b.sr_code,b.pnr_no

My Question is I want a full outer join to combine this two tables query and have the Amount column side by side for comaprison purpose. Mysql handles full outer join by doing LEFT JOIN and Use UNION to combine it with RIGHT join. I used the below query to perform my full outer join but the results are not right. It should give me 17 rows. but it is currently giving me 12 rows and the value of the amount is not correct
****** FULL OUTER JOIN *****
SELECT distinct a.pnr AS PNR, a.station_code as Station,a.date as Date,
sum(a.allamount) as TsrAmount, 
ABS(sum(b.LOC_TAX_AMOUNT + b.LOC_PAX_FARE + b.LOC_SURCHARGE_AMOUNT + b.LOC_SERVICE_FEE_AMOUNT )) as CRAmount 
from daily_posting a LEFT JOIN ticketsalesdetails b 
ON (a.pnr,a.DATE,a.station) = (b.PNR_no,b.date_of_action ,b.sr_code)
Where a.date between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' and a.station_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
group by a.date,a.station_code,a.pnr 

UNION

SELECT distinct a.pnr AS PNR, a.station_code as Station,a.DATE as Date,
sum(a.allamount) as TsrAmount, -1* sum(b.LOC_TAX_AMOUNT + b.LOC_PAX_FARE + b.LOC_SURCHARGE_AMOUNT + b.LOC_SERVICE_FEE_AMOUNT )  as CRAmount 
from daily_posting a RIGHT JOIN ticketsalesdetails b 
ON (a.pnr,a.DATE,a.station) = (b.PNR_no,b.date_of_action ,b.sr_code)
Where a.date between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' and a.station_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
group by a.date,a.station_code,a.pnr

I did a LEFT JOIN AND RIGHT JOIN AND COMBINED BOTH QUERIES WITH UNION BUT THE OUTPUT IS NOT CORRECT

SELECT DISTINCT, GROUP BY and UNION all eliminate duplicates. I.e. absolutely no reason for SELECT DISTINCT here, it just raises many eye-brows.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Removing the DISTINCT did not change anything. The output remains the same.

Exactly. It wasn't needed.

As there are no sample data in your question, so, I tried to solve this issue logically.
Create two different view tables, A, B from daily_posting and ticketsalesdetails with same column name. 
Then use UNION of INNER JOIN (A∩B) and Difference of two table (A-B, B-A) , according to VENN Diagram of OUTER JOIN 

So, you query should be:
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT distinct a.pnr AS PNR, 
        a.station_code as Station,
        cast(a.date as DATE) as Date,
        sum(a.allamount) as amount
    from daily_posting a 
    Where   a.date between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' 
        and a.station_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
    group by a.date,a.station_code,a.pnr 
), t2 AS (
    SELECT distinct 
        b.pnr_NO AS PNR, 
        b.sR_code as Station,
        cast(b.date_OF_ACTION AS Date) as Date,
        ABS(sum(b.LOC_TAX_AMOUNT + b.LOC_PAX_FARE + b.LOC_SURCHARGE_AMOUNT + b.LOC_SERVICE_FEE_AMOUNT )) as amount 
    from ticketsalesdetails b
    Where b.date_of_action between '2024-06-19' and '2024-06-19' 
        and b.sr_code in ('ABVS','BNIA','ABVH') 
    group by b.date_of_action,b.sr_code,b.pnr_no
)

    SELECT t1.PNR,
        t1.Station,
        t1.DATE,
        t1.amount as TsrAmount, 
        t2.amount as CRAmount
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
    ON      t1.PNR = t2.PNR 
        and t1.Station = t2.Station
        and t1.DATE = t2.DATE

UNION ALL 

    SELECT t1.PNR,
        t1.Station,
        t1.DATE,
        t1.amount as TsrAmount,
        '' as CRAmount
    FROM t1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM t2 
        where t1.PNR = t2.PNR 
            and t1.Station = t2.Station
            and t1.DATE = t2.DATE
    )

UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.PNR,
        t2.Station,
        t2.DATE,
        '' as TsrAmount,
        t2.amount as CRAmount
    FROM t2 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM t1 
        where t2.PNR = t1.PNR 
            and t2.Station = t1.Station
            and t2.DATE = t1.DATE
    )    


The analysis was great but it returned with an error. I tried to figure out the issue but it's not working.

Is your t1 and t2 table giving proper output ?  Can you check which section of UNION have issue ? Can you share some sample data ? @FolasopeOludairo

The part of the Query from UNION ALL is where the issue is. Am trying to figure out the problem. The query runs very well except the union ALL  part.

The reason why the UNION ALL didn't work was because the query before it had 5 columns and you want to match it with the two UNION ALL queries which had 4 columns each in your select. Can you provide a rewrite on the queries beginning from the UNION ALL part of the scripts. Thanks

Thanks @Art Bindu, The below is a modified version of what you wrote at the UNION ALL and it works perfectly

Oh, OK OK I understand, what I did mistake there. @FolasopeOludairo
During UNION ALL query I missed out proxy columns of (A-B) & (B-A) section ... as follows: ' ' as TsrAmount, &   ' ' as CRAmount . . .  Please all those columns. I have update the query

What happened to the GROUP BY?

A simpler (and faster) way to get FULL OUTER JOIN is to get both the yellow and orange with one SELECT and get the green witn a second SELECT:

SELECT ...
    FROM a
    ...
UNION ALL
    SELECT ...
        FROM b
        LEFT JOIN a ON ...
        ...
        WHERE a.id IS NULL

Notes:

UNION ALL is faster than UNION or UNION DISTINCT
It is unclear whether the GROUP BY is needed.


I created (a small) FIDDLE

Yes, @RickJames that is also a good idea. Thanks

Emulate FULL OUTER JOIN by the next way:
WITH 
cte1 AS ( {query 1} ),
cte2 AS ( {query 2} ),
cte0 AS ( SELECT PNR, Station, Date FROM cte1
          UNION
          SELECT PNR, Station, Date FROM cte2 )
SELECT PNR, Station, Date, cte1.TsrAmount, cte2.CRAmount
FROM cte0
NATURAL LEFT JOIN cte1
NATURAL LEFT JOIN cte2;

The query assumes that PNR, Station and Date are not NULL.
If these columns may contain NULL then use
WITH 
cte1 AS ( {query 1} ),
cte2 AS ( {query 2} ),
cte0 AS ( SELECT PNR, Station, Date FROM cte1
          UNION
          SELECT PNR, Station, Date FROM cte2 )
SELECT cte0.PNR, cte0.Station, cte0.Date, cte1.TsrAmount, cte2.CRAmount 
FROM cte0
LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte0.PNR <=> cte1.PNR 
              AND cte0.Station <=> cte1.Station 
              AND cte0.Date <=> cte1.Date
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte0.PNR <=> cte2.PNR 
              AND cte0.Station <=> cte2.Station 
              AND cte0.Date <=> cte2.Date;

